# How to get uber ride price

Tags: uber-api

I edited the whole topic because I gave a great read about the whole API and now I'm having another problem ... I'll try to leave as much details as possible here.

The error you are giving is 401 of uber api, but, I did everything right ... My INDEX.html looks like this:

***index.html***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Party Invitation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Party</h1>
        <div class="info-container">
            <span class="info-header">When</span>
            <span class="info when">September 18, 2014 at 6:00pm</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info-container">
            <span class="info-header">Where</span>
            <span class="info where">Thinkful HQ</span>
        </div>
        <img class="map" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.7248,-73.99597&zoom=17&format=png&sensor=false&size=280x280&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry.fill|color:0xf4f4f4&markers=color:red|40.7248,-73.99597&scale=2" alt="">
        <div class="button">
            <p id="time">ESTIMATING TIME</p>
        </div>
    </section>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uber.js"></script>
</body>
```

And then my uber.js is like this:

***uber.js***

```
    // Uber API Constants
var uberClientId = "RxGbzH***************"
    , uberServerToken = "h_hqd3L4***************";

// Create variables to store latitude and longitude
var userLatitude
    , userLongitude
  , partyLatitude = 19.3256725
  , partyLongitude = -43.1579731;



navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
    // Update latitude and longitude
    userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
    userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // Query Uber API if needed
    getEstimatesForUserLocation(userLatitude, userLongitude);
});

function getEstimatesForUserLocation(latitude,longitude) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "KA.ey**********************************************************************************************************************************" + uberServerToken
    },
    data: { 
      start_latitude: latitude,
      start_longitude: longitude,
      end_latitude: partyLatitude,
      end_longitude: partyLongitude
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

[And this is the error that is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOXI.png)

[And my uber control panel is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibkjN.png)

Can anyone tell me why they are giving these two errors on the console? I do not know what to do

=\

Comment: if you don't understand the first link then you probably should learn more about programming in general for whatever language you're using...

Comment: All you need to get started is explained in your first link. You can use your Server Token from your application dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for the sincere opinion of all. I gave one studied and edited the whole topic, if they can give a help I will be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see - your application is not set-up properly. You don't have Redirect URL, Privacy Policy and because you are making API calls from JS - Origin URL:

[image]

[image]

So add something like:

Redirect URL: http://localhost:7000/redirect
Privacy Policy: http://localhost:7000/privacy
Origin URL: http://localhost:7000

I'm not sure where did you get your access token - because you don't have your app set up properly - but even then this will not work because your header is invalid. You are missing token type "Bearer" for access_token. So, in this case, your code should be like:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer KA.ey**********************************************************************************************************************************"
    }
```

If you want to use Server Token:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: "Token uberServerToken"
    }
```

Please read our [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, I have some doubts ...

1 - Can not I use port 80 for localhost?

2 - I can not stop putting some privacy policy? Just for testing ..

3 - Why does not my control panel show the "Origin URL" option? Is this really necessary?

4 - I was thinking that "Rredirect URI" I could just put to redirect to my index.html, which would then be just http: // localhost: 80, in the documentation is not talking very well about it ... So, since not can I put to index.html what should be the redirect URI?

I wait for answers, thank you :)

Comment: 1. Redirect URL can be any dummy URL - we suggest to use some other port then 80.     
2. You dont need policy for testing - but if you want to goto PROD you will need it- so I just gove you tip - this has to be done at some point.     
3. It is available but you need to open "Settings" tab    
4. Redirect URL is used to receive "code" for authentication purpose. I suggest to not use Index.html. Use values I give you. For testing.     
5. I give what to place in each item - use those values - it will work.

Comment: Seriously, I'm pretty stupid hahahahaha I apologize for my ignorance. You know what I was doing wrong? Forgetting to click on "save" ... Omg now understand what people say "Everything has to be very well explained because people err on the dumbest" hahahahah. Thank you very much, friend, if you had not made sure that you answered everything exactly right I would have been burning my head looking for answers being that everything was in front of me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Good you sorted it out..:)